# Visual FoxPro 9 Assign Query to Variable List

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am a C# programmer who is working on a legacy FoxPro (Point of Sale) system, and I would like to know how to assign the results of a dbf query to a variable so I can do something useful with the selected data. In C#, the flow would be to create a model reflecting the database table, run the query, assign results to a List of myModel, and perform subsequent operations on the List of myModel. I get the feeling that FoxPro is different paradigmatically, and I'm having a heck of a time finding information about it online. While my supervisor is way more experienced than me, there is a no-fault communication barrier because we are from different programming eras. Can anybody teach a new dog a trick?

What I would like to do:

```
myVar = SELECT NETINTERACTIVITY.Status;
        FROM NETINTERACTIVITY.DBF NETINTERACTIVITY;
        WHERE ID=myID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FoxPro doesn't let you do a direct assignment from a query that way. You have two options:

1) Store the query result to an array and then use the appropriate array element.

```
SELECT NETINTERACTIVITY.Status;
        FROM NETINTERACTIVITY.DBF NETINTERACTIVITY;
        WHERE ID=myID ;
        INTO ARRAY aStatus
* Now aStatus[1] contains the value you selected
```

Store the query result into a cursor and then use the appropriate field.

```
SELECT NETINTERACTIVITY.Status;
        FROM NETINTERACTIVITY.DBF NETINTERACTIVITY;
        WHERE ID=myID ;
        INTO CURSOR csrStatus
* Now csrStatus.Status contains the value you selected
```